# AppEngine deployment OS error on Mac: [Errno2] "no such file or directory"

Tags: macos, google-app-engine

Deploying my app on AppEngine locally from Terminal, I followed standard procedure with `gcloud app deploy`

However, after the initial deployment steps, I got an error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (OSError): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/my_username/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/Cache/f_029b9c'
```

I changed to that directory and ran `ls` and sure enough there were a ton of files, but not that one. I haven't changed anything since deploying it for the first time yesterday...any ideas?

Comment: Maybe there was something wrong with your latest gcloud update. You could try `gcloud components update` or `gcloud init` to reinitialize gcloud, that might help rebuilding the cache.

Comment: Thanks @brian - Let's say I made a rookie error and the issue is resolved.